# Sourcing a shell script from within Emacs

Tags: shell, shell-script, emacs

I would like to **source** a shell script that changes my environment variables from within Emacs. That is, I would like the shell script to change the environment in which Emacs runs, and I would like to do this from within a running Emacs session.

In other words:

1. I start Emacs from `zsh`
2. I would like to source a `zsh` script from within Emacs that changes environment variables such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

#### Background:

This is an attempt to circumvent the problem that I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227478/emacs-anaconda-linking-problems), where I need to **set** `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to run Emacs, but I need to **unset** it to run a specific Python distribution ([Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)).

Specifically, I want to use an Emacs package ([emacs-jedi](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi)) that requires access to this Python distribution, but currently I need to **unset** `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` first to start Emacs, so I would need to **set** it later so that I can use `emacs-jedi` from within Emacs.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: What do you mean _within_ emacs? What kind of environment variables are we talking about? Do you mean in an eshell (or other emacs shell) instance? What do the environment variables actually do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, since each time you're invoking a subshell to source the script you're invoking a child process from the original process where the emacs applications was launched.

The exporting of environment variables is a one way street where only the parent can provide variables to any child processes, but no child processes can manipulate the parent's environment.

#### Experiment

I'm using `vim` but the same should apply to `emacs`. Sample file to source.

```
$ more ~/vars.bash 
export VAR=somevalue
```

1. Initial Parent environment, `$VAR` is unset

   ```
   $ echo $VAR

   $
   ```
2. Launch `vim`. Then invoke a subshell to source the above file (`:sh`).

   ```
   # check variable
   $ echo $VAR

   $

   # source and re-check
   $ source ~/vars.bash
   $ echo $VAR
   somevalue
   ```
3. Exit subshell, return to vim. Then invoke another subshell (`:sh`).

   ```
   $ exit

   ... back in vim, do another `:sh` ...

   # check variable
   $ echo $VAR

   $
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH after loading Emacs, just add

```
(setenv "LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
```

to `~/.emacs` or other init file.

If you need to swap back and forth, save the result of `(getenv "LD_LIBRARY_PATH")` in a variable first so you can restore it later.

Comment: Thanks! - I have started a thread on this possibility: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93947/appending-values-to-env-variable-from-within-emacs

Answer (score 1):

I've found this nice piece of Emacs lisp that uses `diff` to compare outputs of `export` command before and after sourcing, and then calls `setenv` function accordingly:
https://gist.github.com/ffevotte/9345586