# Appending values to environment variables from within Emacs

Tags: emacs, environment-variables

I am using Elisp. I would like to do the following in my init file:

```
; Retrieve the value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH
; Append '/path/to/some/lib/:'to it
; Save the new value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

So far I know that I can use:

```
(getenv "LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
```

to retrieve the value, and:

```
(setenv "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "foo")
```

to set a new value, but my knowledge of Elisp is extremely rudimentary so I don't know to proceed from this point.

#### Background:

This question is inspired by the fact that it is [not be possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93947/appending-values-to-env-variable-from-within-emacs) to source a shell script to manipulate this environment from within Emacs, so I would need to do this using Elisp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Elisp, string concatenation is done with `concat`:

```
(setenv "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
  (let ((current (getenv "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))
        (new "/path/to/some/lib"))
    (if current (concat new ":" current) new)))
```